# Linearization of a quadratic function in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functions, quadratic-forms, linearization

In my research, I came across with a undesirable quadratic function that must be linearized. I am wondering whether it is possible.  The problem is described in the following.

Let  the function

> \begin{array} {lcl} f:  (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \times [-1,1] \longrightarrow (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)\\  \hspace{1cm}(x,y)\longmapsto  xy. \end{array}

Assuming $\varepsilon << 1$, my question is:

> Is there some real values $a,b$ and $c$ such that 
>   $$f(x,y) \approx ax +by +c?$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a neighborhood of what point?

Comment: @AdamHughes, actually all points in the domain of $f$. In order words, I am looking for the linear form closer to $f(x,y)$.

Comment: It's a smooth function, so you can always find some plane using the usual $f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)(x-a)+f_y(a,b)(y-b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXllP.png) of your function ($\epsilon = 0.05$ here, but the picture will look indistinguishable for any other choice, as long as you rescale the height). The best you can do is probably the plane $f(x, y) \approx 0$, just from looking at all the symmetry.

A plane that does well for $y$ around $-1$ will do terribly for $y$ close to $1$. Same for $x$. Just picking the middle ground seems as good an option as any.

Comment: Ok! I will compute the closest linear form to $f(x,y)$ to verify your claim. Thanks!